# I can not deploy google cloud functions in any project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I used to deploy google cloud functions in the previous days. They were successful. But now I can not deploy cloud functions in any project. An unknown error is coming, See the below image.

[image]

Comment: If this is a persistent issue, you will need to reach out to google support!

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting cache from browser, or use another browser. Try also in icognito mode, and if it doesnt work, then contact support!

Comment: Also, turn on the browser debugger, Sometimes details are logged that might help.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it. I did it this way.